# OCAPI API for Salesforce Commerce Cloud - How to query for custom fields

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am working with the OCAPI api to try and query some custom fields in the customer object using the customer_search endpoint. It is a text field that stores JSON data, I am not sure why it was every created that way, but it stores a specific credit id we use to share with other business. My task is to search for this credit id and pull back the customer info.

I am using this endpoint:

`https://{host}/s/-/dw/data/v23_2/customer_lists/{customer_list_id}/customer_search`

The problem I have is that I am unable to get any information from this field for some reason.

The queries that I have tried are:

```
body = {
    "query":
        {
            "text_query": {"fields": ["c_creditIDInfo"], "search_phrase": "YJy0RIMQL5"}
        },
        "select": "(**)"
}
```

Which results in

`Failed: 500, {"_v":"23.2","fault":{"type":"InternalServerErrorException","message":"Internal Server Error"}}`

then if I try something like

```
body = {
    "query":
        {
            "term_query": {"fields": ["c_creditIDInfo"], "operator": "is_not_null"}
        },
        "select": "(**)"
}
```

I get the same error

`Failed: 500, {"_v":"23.2","fault":{"type":"InternalServerErrorException","message":"Internal Server Error"}}`

Querying any standard field like the customer_no, first_name or email works perfectly fine, it is just this custom text field.

The text field in SFCC is like a html memo field that stores data like this, as you can see it's escaped as its already in a string field.

```
"c_creditIDInfo": 
    "{\"application\": [
        {\"creditID\":\"YJy0RIMQL5\",\"applied\":1619744212531},
        {\"creditID\":\"fTZGE6PoNE\",\"applied\":1667934833987},
        {\"creditID\":\"a9YnXgexZF\",\"applied\":1623025992609}
        ]
    }",
```

I am proficient in Python so all I want the query to do is pull back any customers where "c_creditIDInfo" is not null and then I can parse the JSON in Python.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).